# How to add an incrementing integer/string line together?

Tags: python

How do I increment a number on the same line as a string? I have this so far:

```
file = open('test.ipynb')
text = file.readlines()
count = 0
for lines in text:
    lineNumbers = print(str[count] + '\t' + lines)    
    count += 1
```

This adds them both but for whatever reason the number is replaced with a 't' on the left side. Any thoughts?

Comment: 1) why are you adding 0 to `count`? 2) Was `count` supposed to be defined before the `for` loop? 3) Why are you assigning the result of `print` to `lineNumbers`? 4) What is `str[i]` supposed to do? Having expected input and output would help answer your question

Comment: I edited the peice  on the post. It should have the parts tha tyou're looking for.

Comment: Has `str` Been redefined somewhere? `str[count]` is not valid python code. If that is not throwing an error, the only thing I can think is that something like  `str = “test.ipynb”` Has happened somewhere along the way

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `str(count)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` to "count" the lines:

```
file = open('test.ipynb')

text = file.readlines()

for i, lines in enumerate(text):

        lineNumbers = print(str(i) + '\t' + lines)
```

Comment: This is the result when using this answer:                                                                                                  t {

e  "cells": [

s   {

t    "cell_type": "code",

.    "execution_count": 2,

i    "metadata": {},

p    "outputs": [

y     {

n      "ename": "SyntaxError",

b      "evalue": "invalid syntax (<ipython-input-2-c437b178598e>, line 11)",

Comment: That cannot be the output of the code in the answer. Did you copy and past exactly? The "t" that is beginning printed suggests that the code you are running is slightly different than what is above

Comment: Yes I did. The code answered to me simply plays out the string until it has reached the end of the letters in 'test.ipynb.'

Comment: you should use `str(count)` insted of `str[count]`

Comment: @IsaacHayman you might be doing `str = "test.ipynb"` somewhere

Comment: Using str(count) instead of str[count] reads me "'str' object is not callable"

Comment: @IsaacHayman It sounds like you're shadowing `str`. Are you assigning `str` to something earlier in your code?